# Is there a formula for the second implicit derivative like for the first?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

The formula for the first implicit derivative dy/dx = -fx/fy where fx and fy are the respective partial derivatives. Is there such a formula for the second implicit derivative? (d2y/dx^2)

Comment: Your description of the first implicit derivative is not complete. You need to mention it is for a function $y$ defined implicitly by a formula $f(x,y)=c$ [constant $c$] and use $f_x, f_y$ for the partials [not fx and fy.]

Comment: Yes. Differentiate again the formula, from where the first derivative is obtained.

Comment: @zkutch I don't know the formula and I can't find any information about it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know, that, in appropriate conditions, equation $F(x,y)=0$ defines function, called [implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function), $y=f(x)$.

Putting this function in equation gives identity
$$F(x,f(x))=0$$
Differentiation of this identity gives
$$F'_x(x,f(x))+F'_y(x,f(x))f'(x)=0$$
From where comes formula for first derivative. Now, differentiate it again, and putting expression for $f'$ we have
$$f''_{x^2}=\frac{(F''_{xy}+F''_{y^2}f'_x)\cdot F'_x - (F''_{x^2}+F''_{xy}f'_x)\cdot F'_x}{F'^{2}_y}=\\
=\frac{2F'_x\cdot F'_y\cdot F''_{xy}-F'^{2}_y\cdot F''_{x^2}-F'^{2}_x\cdot F''_{y^2}}{F'^{3}_y}$$
Same way you can use for 3d and high derivatives. If/when you would like read it from book, then look at G.M. Fichtenholz, A Course of Differential and Integral Calculus, I volume.